# Colon in variable identifier

Tags: python, postgis, geodjango

Is it possible to have a colon in a variable name ? 
I already tried to backslash it but it doesn't work...

I'm using geoDjango so my identifiers in my models have to keep the same name than those in the database. The trouble is that, as I migrated data from OSM, I have some columns which are named with a colon (ie addr:housenumber)

Here's an example :

```
class myClass(models.Model):
# ...
addr:housename = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

When I'm trying to syncdb :

```
addr:housename = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which seems normal. When I try to escape the colon, I have another error :

```
addr\:housename = models.TextField(blank=True)
                                             ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I really don't understand why I got this error.

Someone knows how to put column in an identifier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#db-column) field parameter to specify your real column name. And yes, colons are not allowed in identifiers names in python.

```
class myClass(models.Model):
    addr_housename = models.TextField(blank=True, db_column="addr:housename")
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the colon is simply not allowed in Python variable names. You can only have letters, digit and underscores. Actually, you should replace all the colons by underscores if possible.

If your variable is class attribute - it does not seem to be the case here -, you can use `setattr` and `getattr` to have class attribute names with wathever character you want in them, but that will be ugly, and you won't be able to use them without `setattr` and `getattr` anymore. Here is an example:

```
class A: pass

a = A()
setattr(a, 'addr:housename', models.TextField(blank=True))
some_var = getattr(a, 'addr:housename')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you define multiple models and linked them by foreign key just like what you should do in Entity–relationship model:

```
class Address(models.Model)
    housename = models.TextField(blank=True)
    ...

class myClass(models.Model):
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address')
    ...
```